# Backbone Marionette - How to get return data in view template using fetch method

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, fetch

In my app, I am using `passport` - authenticate on login, once the login is success, I am redirecting to home page like this:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/#home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash : true
    }));
```

I am getting redirected to `home` page. on redirecting to home page I am passing user info like this from router:

```
router.get('/#home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});
```

Now I would like to receive the user details.. for that I am getting the data using model like:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone){
    "use strict";
    socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

    socialApp.homeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'/home',
        defaults:{
            name:"from home"
        },
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('from home Model'); //works!
        }
    });

    return socialApp.homeModel;
});
```

In the view, I am fetching the data from model like:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'hbs!scripts/templates/home/homeTemp'],
    function ($,_,Backbone, Marionette, homeTemp) {
        "use strict";
        socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

        socialApp.homeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template:homeTemp(),
            initialize:function () {
                console.log('view init');
                this.model.fetch({
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data); // but nothing happening!
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return socialApp.homeView;
});
```

Any one help me to identify the wrong what i do here? and can any one help me to get the data please?

**Update**

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
        console.log('req.user is ' + req.user) // i am getting correct out put here. how to send to mode.fetch..?
        return { user: req.user }; // after redering generic html(index) returning the object.
    });
```

Comment: what is `res` here  `res.render('index'...` ?

Comment: That is the index file for all views. I am rendering the different screens in the index.html container.

Comment: ok, could you please attach code part that maintain what view to render ?

Comment: I am using controller to load the views. I am picking the controller according to the url.

Comment: ok, so controller might receives 2 params (`pageName` and `data`) ? do you proxy `data` u pass to controller to loaded view ? do this view use `options` on initialize to grab data from controller ?

Comment: No, I just load the controller according to the url, and the controller takes care to load the model and view... once the view loads it fetching the data from model.  I am using localhost and node.

Comment: please see my last update, which i return the data on get('home').

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61326/discussion-between-evgeniy-and-3gwebtrain).

Comment: Does it actually try to fetch? if so what is the response from the server if its an error or unparsable json then it will not run the success,if it doesn't try to fetch what is this.model

Comment: this.model is defined by controller. on `/home` - i am passing the user credientials, but i am not able to get that the mode fetch.

Comment: I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` on get of `home`.

Comment: Did you check the server response? That would tell you if the fetch is actually fetching the data or not

Answer (score 0):

I updated my route to send the data like this: it works for me

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        return res.send(req.user);
    });
```

Any way, thanks to all..

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're not using controllers at all? I typically handle it like this in my controllers (after my router routes them here).

```
@SampleApp.module "PostsApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class List.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: ->
        posts = App.request "post:entities"

        App.execute "when:fetched", posts, =>
            @layout = @getLayoutView()

            @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @postsRegion posts

        @show @layout
```

When fetched basically just waits until the entity is fetched and then runs the code block after - i.e. lazy load.